# Rails 4 N+1 query present with includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, performance

I'm using the [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet), and it's notifying me of N+1 query. Here is how my models are connected:

```
class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meeting_notes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Now meeting notes class :

```
class MeetingNote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :department
  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :budget_year
  belongs_to :notes_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :n_app_user_id
  belongs_to :leading_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: :l_app_user_id    
end
```

Department and status have methods and db columns `department_name` and `status_name`. User has `first_name` and `last_name` db columns, and active record model has a method `full_name` which returns concatenation of `first_name` and `last_name` or empty string if there is none of those in the db.

So when I display info about particular meeting like this (if you ignore the wrong synthax):

```
Name: #{Meeting_name}
Notes: 
For department: #{Department_name}
With status: #{Status_name}
Notes taking user: #{Notes_user_full_name}
User taking initiative: #{Leading_user_full_name}
```

This fires N+1 query like this :

```
N+1 Query detected
  meeting_note => [:leading_user]
  Add to your finder: :includes => [:leading_user]
```

And this is my query :

```
Meeting.includes(meeting_notes: [:department, :status, :notes_user, :leading_user])
.where('budget_year.budget_year_id + ?', by_id).references(:budget_year)
```

However when I remove the `leading_user` from query and ui view, query like this :

```
Meeting.includes(meeting_notes: [:department, :status, :notes_user])
    .where('budget_year.budget_year_id + ?', by_id).references(:budget_year)
```

Or if I leave the `leading_user` on query and ui view and I take out the `notes_user` the N+1 query doesn't show up.

It's not just the bullet thing, it's when I look at the logs as well. When there are bullet warning I see multiple selects from user table which would be the N+1 queries. When there is no bullet warnings I don't see individual select from users query. What do I do here to avoid the N+1 ?

**Anyone had similar experience? How did you fix it?**

Comment: `:notes_user` and `:leading_user` both reference the same table (`User`). Maybe that is why it is generating this problem (possibly a false positive). Try this: on your `includes`, put `:leading_user` before `:notes_user`. In this scenario, we expect bullet to report the problem but complaining about `notes_user` instead. If this is the case, probably bullet is reporting a false positive and we will have to look at the logs to see if it indeed is.

Comment: What rails 4 version are you using because I have seen this with `eager_load` where it does not work appropriately especially with null sets. e.g. if there is no leading_user for a meeting_note then it will execute a query just to return nothing.

Comment: @cenouro yes that is the case, but I can see the individual user queries being fired, and those are the N+1

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow in that case I think this is a limitation on behalf of Rails `#includes`. Maybe open a pull request on their repo.